# Get Category Archive Template Name Dynamically

Tags: wp-query, categories

I'm making a category archive template that works for *all* my categories. I need to dynamically set the `'category'` parameter of `WP_Query` inside of this template to make it work.

How do I dynamically get a string of the current category page name to feed into the WP_Query? All the methods I've seen presupposed that I know my `ID` or `slug`. As this is an archive page, most WP functions will not return the archive page title but rather a post title.

The best option I've see is:
`$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);`

But it still displays the title on my `category.php` page - maybe I'm doing something wrong with this?

Comment: is there a reason you can't use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query?

Comment: Not familiar - would love to see how you use it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only option I have found:

```
$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, [`get_queried_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) and [`get_queried_object_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) will give you all the info you need about most types of pages.

However- if you're creating a new query in the template to change some query parameters, then you should instead be using [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query before it's run. Then you can just run the regular loop in your template.

For example, changing `posts_per_page` on a category archive:

```
function wpd_category_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 15 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','wpd_category_query' );
```